# Getting "Operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'method group' and 'method group'" when trying to chain delegatees (multicast delegate)

Tags: c#, delegates, operator-overloading, multicastdelegate

The following code

```cs
public class TypeTests {
    delegate int LogMessageDelegate(string message);
    
    int LogMessageToConsoleReturn1(string msg) {
        Console.WriteLine($"{msg} return 1");
        return 1;
    }

    int LogMessageToConsoleReturn2(string msg) {
        Console.WriteLine($"{msg} return 2");
        return 2;
    }

    [Fact]
    public void DelegateInvokesMethod() {
        LogMessageDelegate log;
        // log = LogMessageToConsoleReturn1; // assign to a method group
        // log += LogMessageToConsoleReturn2; // multicast using += works just fine
        log = LogMessageToConsoleReturn1 + LogMessageToConsoleReturn2; // multicast using + causes CS0019 compiler error
        Assert.Equal(2, log("Hello"));
    }
}
```

is causing a [CS0019 compiler error](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0019) with the following message

> Operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'method group' and 'method group'

It should work per [How to combine delegates (Multicast Delegates)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/how-to-combine-delegates-multicast-delegates) which states

> multiple objects can be assigned to one delegate instance by using the + operator.

and furthermore provides the example

> ```
> multiDel = hiDel + byeDel;
> ```

where `hiDel` and `byeDel` are each a method group. [EDIT: I think I was mistaken; `hiDel` and `byeDel` are each a delegate, not a method group, by this point in the code.]

---

Using `+=` works. I.e., if I change the test to

```cs
    [Fact]
    public void DelegateInvokesMethod() {
        LogMessageDelegate log;
        log = LogMessageToConsoleReturn1; // assign to a method group
        log += LogMessageToConsoleReturn2; // multicast using += works just fine
        // log = LogMessageToConsoleReturn1 + LogMessageToConsoleReturn2; // multicast using + causes CS0019 compiler error
        Assert.Equal(2, log("Hello"));
    }
```

then it compiles, runs, and passes just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have instances of your delegate before you combine them unfortunately. Below I named them `first` and `second`.

```cs
public class TypeTests
{
    delegate int LogMessageDelegate(string message);

    int LogMessageToConsoleReturn1(string msg)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{msg} return 1");
        return 1;
    }

    int LogMessageToConsoleReturn2(string msg)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{msg} return 2");
        return 2;
    }

    [Fact]
    public void DelegateInvokesMethod()
    {
        LogMessageDelegate log, first, second;
        // log = LogMessageToConsoleReturn1; // assign to a method group
        // log += LogMessageToConsoleReturn2; // multicast using += works just fine
        first = LogMessageToConsoleReturn1;
        second = LogMessageToConsoleReturn2;
        log = first + second; // multicast using + causes CS0019 compiler error
        Assert.Equal(2, log("Hello"));
    }
}
```

But there's also another way to do it, a small trick:

```cs
log = (LogMessageDelegate)LogMessageToConsoleReturn1 + LogMessageToConsoleReturn2;
```

Comment: Thanks! I wonder if `first = LogMessageToConsoleReturn1;` is doing an implicit cast -- from method group to delegate. Or maybe it's shorthand for `first = new LogMessageDelegate(LogMessageToConsoleReturn1);`?